# Подключение скриптов в WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, cms

Подключил `jQuey UI` и `jQuery`, а также скрипт, который их использует. Однако `jQuery UI` не "видит" подключенный `jQuery` (мой скрипт `coursel.js` не находит ничего) хотя библиотека подключена самая первая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    function add_scripts () {
        wp_register_script('html5-shim', 'http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js');
        wp_register_script( 'jone', get_template_directory_uri() .'/jquery-1.7.1.js' );
        wp_register_script( 'jtwo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ui.core.js');
        wp_register_script( 'jfour', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ui.widget.js' );
        wp_register_script( 'jthree', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ui.rcarousel.js' );
        wp_register_script( 'jfive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/coursel.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jone' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jtwo' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jthree' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jfour' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jfive' );
        wp_enqueue_script('html5-shim');

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

Comment: Так `jquery ui` не находит `jquery` или ваш `coursel.js`? И что значит "не находит"? Может вы как-то не правильно его используете?

Comment: @ВОРОН для работы jquery ui нужен jquery.И выскакивает ошибка будто он непоключен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция **wp_register_script** принимает третий параметр - список зависимостей. В таком случае будет учитываться порядок загрузки скриптов. UI видимо загружается раньше, чем jQuery. jQuery всегда есть в поставке WP по-умолчанию. Если ваша версия должна быть второй мажорности, то лишь тогда необходимо переназначить jQuery.

Пример указания зависимости:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ui.core.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
```